# How are the ethers sent to smart contract in the IBM example

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I was reading the [IBM Example](https://developer.ibm.com/clouddataservices/2016/05/19/block-chain-technology-smart-contracts-and-ethereum/) about smartSponsor, and there is this following code:

```
personal.unlockAccount(thesponsor,"password"); 
ss.pledge("Good luck with the run!", {from: thesponsor, value: 10000000, gas: 3000000});
```

While the function pledge is:

```
function pledge(bytes32 _message) {
  if (msg.value == 0 || complete || refunded) throw;
  pledges[numPledges] = Pledge(msg.value, msg.sender, _message);
  numPledges++;
}

struct Pledge {
  uint amount;
  address eth_address;
  bytes32 message;
}
```

I was looking for "send" or "transfer" functions. But I could not find any. Therefore I was confused how were the ethers sent from the sponsor to the smart contract?

Update:

How did the sender send the ethers? I was expecting something like .transfer(uint256 amount) or .send(uint256 amount). But it seems that there is no such function call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are in magical variable [msg](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html). The function pledge uses this variable in the following line:

```
pledges[numPledges] = Pledge(msg.value, msg.sender, _message);
```

Comment: But how did the sender send the ethers? I was expecting something like <address>.transfer(uint256 amount) or <address>.send(uint256 amount). But it seems that there is no such function call?

Comment: Your default account is used for that.